# Laravel. Отправка в очередь большого количества джоб

Tags: laravel, очередь

Решаю задачу импорта базы данных в реструктурированную новую.
Есть настроенный супервайзер, который запускает джобы. 
Запуск произвожу из консоли через кастомную команду, которая отправляет джобу, с самым высоким приоритетом, которая уже отправляет в очередь остальные.

```
$blogArticles = Blog::with('getAuthor')->get();

    foreach ($blogArticles as $blogArticle)
    {
        $articleWriter = new DataWriter($blogArticle);
        dispatch(new ImportData($articleWriter))->onQueue($this->queuePriority)->delay(60*50);
    }
```

В DataWriter идет уже обработка импорта. Так сделано для того, чтобы не было времени ожидания при отправки джоб в очередь. Но тут возникает проблема: самих $blogArticles более 80 тыс, а процесс раскидывания джоб затухает где-то на 3600. Т.е. явно время жизни джобы ограничено.

Собственно вопрос в том, как решить проблему, и как сделать правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено с помощью чанков.
Чанками отправляю коллекции в класс, раскидывающий джобы обработчика. Т.е. ставлю в в очередь с высоким приоритетом задачи, по раскидыванию в очередь джоб с обработкой записи каждой статьи.